# Is there a generic way to make this conversion?

Tags: c#, object, type-conversion

Below code works when I input it with a string like "15" but when I give it an integer like 15,  it gives me error saying " Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String".

How can I edit this code to allow for integer inputs also? Note: I make conversion inside for loop

```
using System;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication24
{
internal class Program
{
    public static void ThreadMethod(object o)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse((string)o); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t.Start("15");
        t.Join();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `TheVariable.ToString()` ?

Comment: this seems like a very bad idea. normalize it going in.

Comment: Methods should be explicit in what they expect as input. passing an `object` when what the method wants is an `int` is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public static void ThreadMethod(object o)
{
    var limit = o is string ? Int32.Parse((string)o) : (int)o;
    // OR  var limit = Int32.Parse(o.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted? This answer seems to be the only one that answer the question... ?

Comment: But he asked only for int and string... otherwise since c# 7 you can use switch to determine other expected types...

Comment: This looks elegant

Answer (score 1):

Just pass an `int` instead of a string and drop the `Int32.Parse((string)o)` part and cast `o` to `int`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)o; i++)
```

If you want to support strings as well, you'll have to do some investigation (here using C# 7's pattern matching):

```
int val = /* some default */;
if (o is int oInt) val = oInt;
if (o is string oString) val = Int32.Parse(oString);
```

If you need more data than a single parameter, you'll have to pass an object (and cast that).

```
class Data
{
    string oString { get; set; }
    int oInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but if I do that "15" input will not work this time. I need both inputs work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do here. By far the easiest is to not use that type of conversion. As you're going to a string, it is very easy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Int32.Parse(o.ToString()); i++)...
```

However, a cleaner way to to that would be to overload your method:

```
public static void ThreadMethod(object o)
{
    ThreadMethod(Int32.Parse(o.ToString()));
}

public static void ThreadMethod(int o)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadProc: {0}", i);
        Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Even though that adds to the amount of code, it makes your methods far more readable. You can also separate out your call to the `int` method by doing checks before calling it. Oftentimes, you'll run into situations where you'll want to do more than just call the other method. Even still, this way removes the ambiguity and possibility of failure within the method that is doing what you want.